# Looping Through Gridview with IF ELSE statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to add a conditional statement to a GridView; however,it appears to only be working on the first row.

I have a HiddenField where I am extracting my discount value and then a Label
where I am returning said value, only if the value is not 0.00 else its should create a break. 
I was assuming I could simply loop through the grid rows to accomplish this; however, as earlier stated it is only working on the first row. Here is my code:

```
    // Number of rows in grid
            int rowsCount = grid.Rows.Count;
            //Loop through the rows
            for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
            {
                Label discountLabel = (Label)(grid.Rows[0].FindControl("discountLabel"));
                HiddenField discount = (HiddenField)(grid.Rows[0].FindControl("HiddenField1"));
                string discountValue = discount.Value;
                if (discountValue == "0.00")
                {
                    discountLabel.Text = "<br />";
                }
                else
                {
                    discountLabel.Text = "NOW&nbsp;" + (String.Format("{0:c}", discountValue));
                }
            }
```

Comment: change grid.Rows[0] to grid.Rows[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grid.Rows[0]` returns the first row in the grid, you want to loop all rows. So use the loop variable `i` instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
{
    Label discountLabel = (Label)(grid.Rows[i].FindControl("discountLabel"));
    HiddenField discount = (HiddenField)(grid.Rows[i].FindControl("HiddenField1"));
    string discountValue = discount.Value;
    if (discountValue == "0.00")
    {
        discountLabel.Text = "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        discountLabel.Text = "NOW&nbsp;" + (String.Format("{0:c}", discountValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh goodness, either I am blind or have not had enough coffee today! Thank you. I will mark as right answer in 10min when it lets me.

Comment: @Faron: by the way, you can't use `String.Format("{0:c}", discountValue)` if `discountValue` is a string. Then you don't get the currency format since that works only with numeric types like `decimal` or `double`. Therefore parse it first: `decimal discount = decimal.Parse(discountValue)`. Now you can use `String.Format("{0:c}", discount)`